# How to turn off hyphenation in ToC only?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyphenation, tocloft

Here's what my template looked like before:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

I changed it to this:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}{\cftsecfont}{\raggedright}
```

but ToC still hyphenates.

How do I turn off hyphenation in the ToC?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: What should happen instead of hyphenation?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139740/hyphenation-in-a-table-of-contents-causing-bad-blocks

Answer (score 4):

I've found the `\hyphenchar` approach to work well in my documents:

```
\hyphenchar\font=-1 % disable hyphen
\tableofcontents
\hyphenchar\font=`\- % reset hyphen
```

Answer (score 3):

It could be done in the following way without the `tocloft` package:

```
\begingroup
\raggedright
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

Comment: In some cases, LaTeX still hyphenates.