# Hyphenation in a table of contents causing bad blocks

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, hyphenation

I want to turn off words hyphenation in a TOC but leave it in the rest of a document. The intention to do it is to avoid bad blocks such as you can see below in my MWE.

I prefer a solution that wouldn't use other packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt, DIV = calc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left = 3cm, right = 2cm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
\chapter{Loremipsum dolor sitametar consectetu adipisicin aberm models}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with package `ragged2e`:

```
\begingroup
\RaggedRight
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

Comment: The `\RaggedRight` won't prohibit all hyphenation. To really turn off all hyphenation in a flush-left setting, use `\raggedright` (note: no uppercase letters).

Comment: Hyphenation should be allowed!

Comment: I actually fully agree with you on the proposition that hyphenation *should* be allowed in a TOC. It's just that the OP has stated explicitly that he/she does not want hyphenation. In such cases, it might be a good idea to be up front about the fact that solution does not give the customer precisely what's been asked for, but something even better. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Setting `\pretolerance=10000` (and going back to the preceeding value after Contents) turns off words hyphenation, but I am afraid that it may cause, not solve, problems. Maybe simply using `\sloppy` to the chosen part of your document is the right solution?

Comment: Unfortunately your solution causes two wide space between words

Comment: @megabyde the definition of `\sloppy` is  `\tolerance 9999\emergencystretch 3em\hfuzz .5\p@ \vfuzz \hfuzz `. Perhaps you can try this with `3em` replaced by `1.5em`, and the `9999` could be set perhaps to `10000` and see what comes out.