# No hyphenation in TOC entries, please

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script, hyphenation, tocloft

I have some very long section titles and do not want their entries in the TOC to be hyphenated.
[image: example output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{section}{0mm}{12mm}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0mm}{12mm}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{This kind of problem, that kind of problem, other ones and further considerations}
\section{More problems, even more problems, much worse than these, headline hyphenation, and blablablablablablablablabla and XYZ-blablablablablablablablabla}
\end{document}
```

From some googling, I got the impression that `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\raggedright}` should help, but it does not. Neither does `\begingroup \raggedright \tableofcontents \endgroup` from [the only (not accepted) answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132266/how-to-turn-off-hyphenation-in-toc-only). (When I uncomment `\usepackage{ngerman]{babel}`, the hyphenation of "consid-erations" changes to "consi-derations", interestingly.)

The problem occurs also when I do not use `tocloft` or when I change the document class to `book`, for example (with hyphenation at different syllables).

Can I make hyphenation in the TOC go away completely, without resorting to re-defining it for every offending word?! Bonus points if the solution does not make long words go over the line like the final "blabla...", even more bonus points if word combinations that contain a hyphen to begin with ("XYZ-blabla") can be brought on the same line.

Comment: Try `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil} \makeatother`. The command `\@tocrmarg` fills up the Right side of the TOC MARGin; it needs to be bigger than the Page NUMber WIDTH, or `\@pnumwidth`.

Comment: @jon - You should make this comment an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. I added one (though I think Gonzalo is right).

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139740/hyphenation-in-a-table-of-contents-causing-bad-blocks

Comment: It is not recommended to use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using a KOMA class, the way to go is to use the [`tocstyle`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/tocstyle.pdf) package:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}

\newtocstyle{raggedstyle}{%
  \settocstylefeature[0]{entryhook}{\bfseries}
  \settocstylefeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}
  \settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
  \settocfeature{spaceafternumber}{17pt}
}
\usetocstyle{raggedstyle}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{This kind of problem, that kind of problem, other ones and further considerations}
\section{More problems, even more problems, much worse than these, headline with no hyphenation and somo more text goes here for the example}

\end{document}
```

Refer to the package documentation for further adjustments.

Comment: Thank you! I had a look at tocstyle before, but felt I did not understand the manual well enough to try defining my own toc style.

Answer (score 6):

I think I'd be inclined to use Gonzalo Medina's answer given you are using `scrreprt` (and skip loading `tocloft`), but a `tocloft` solution isn't too tricky (and also useful for `memoir` users):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{section}{0mm}{12mm}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0mm}{12mm}

\makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{\@pnumwidth plus1fil} % <-- Revised
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{This kind of problem, that kind of problem, other ones and further considerations}
\section{More problems, even more problems, much worse than these, headline hyphenation, and blablablablablablablablabla and XYZ-blablablablablablablablabla}

\end{document}
```

You should, in general, make sure the revised value for `\@tocrmarg` (TOC Right MARGin) is greater than that for `\@pnumwidth` (Page NUMber WIDTH).

Comment: You could use `\@pnumwidth` directly in the redefinition of `\@tocrmarg`, i.e., set `\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{\@pnumwidth plus1fil}`.

Comment: @Mico -- That's an obvious improvement.  Good idea!

Answer (score 3):

The usage of package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. Here is a suggestion without this package and without the redefinition of an internal command:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocindent=0mm,
  tocnumwidth=12mm,
  tocraggedentrytext
]{chapter,section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{This kind of problem, that kind of problem, other ones and further considerations}
\section{More problems, even more problems, much worse than these, headline hyphenation, and blablablablablablablablabla and XYZ-blablablablablablablablabla}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You could also use class option `toc=flat` instead setting `tocindent=0mm` and `tocnumwidth=12mm`:

```
\documentclass[toc=flat]{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedentrytext
]{chapter,section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{This kind of problem, that kind of problem, other ones and further considerations}
\section{More problems, even more problems, much worse than these, headline hyphenation, and blablablablablablablablabla and XYZ-blablablablablablablablabla}
\end{document}
```

Note that there is an additional run needed for the alignment.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `titletoc` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[12mm]
 {\contentsmargin{10mm}\bigskip\sffamily\bfseries\Large}
 {\contentslabel[\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel}]{12mm}}
 {}
 {\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]


 \titlecontents{section}[12mm]
 { \rightskip=10mm plus 1fil\hyphenpenalty=10000\contentsmargin{2mm}}%
 {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{12mm}}
 {}
 {\hskip2pt\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{100}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{This kind of problem, that kind of problem, other ones and further considerations}
\section{More problems, even more problems, much worse than these, headline hyphenation, and blablablablablablablablabla and XYZblablablablablablablablabla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Yes, it's a problem with my editor configuration, and I didn't check the code. Thanks for pointing that. It's corrected now.