# Is it possible to disable hyphenation only for TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyphenation, tocloft

I want to keep hyphenation across the document but to be disabled in TOC

[This code is not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430173/disable-hyphenation-in-toc)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatother
```

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\linespread{1.2}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} %clear page TOC
\newcommand\Dotfill{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


%----------hypenation---------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\emergencystretch=10pt      % allows some extra whitespace per line.
\exhyphenpenalty=100        % allows using hyphens which were already present.
% \hyphenpenalty=10000        % disables hyphens completly.

%-------------Title Chap & Section------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\Large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\filleft\bfseries\large}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}


\titleformat
{\chapter}                       % command
[display]                        % shape
{\Huge\bfseries\raggedleft}      % format
{}                               % label
{22pt}                           % separation between label and chapter-title
{\Huge}[\vspace{1ex}]            % before-code

\titleformat
{\section}                       % command
[display]                        % shape
{\Huge\bfseries\raggedleft}      % format
{}                               % label
{25pt}                           % separation between label and chapter-title
{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}]            % before-code

% \titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large\raggedleft}{}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedleft}{}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedleft}{}{0.5em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{1ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{1ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{6ex}

\newcommand{\autor}[1]{\textbf{\Large {#1}}\medskip\par}
\newcommand{\scoala}[1]{\textit{\normalsize{#1}}\medskip\par}
% \newcommand{\prof}[1]{\textit{\small prof. coord. {#1}}\\ \smallskip}

\newcommand{\prof}[1]{%
    \par\begingroup\linespread{1}\small\itshape
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
    \par\endgroup\smallskip
}

\begin{document}

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\cftsetrmarg{4cm}
\cftsetindents{part}{0cm}{1cm}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1cm}{0cm}
\cftsetindents{section}{1cm}{0cm}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2cm}{0cm}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is part I}

\chapter{Specii. Discurs și comportament politicianist în literatura noastră de secol XIX și XX}
\begin{flushright}
    \autor{Student Name}
    \scoala{Name of School}
    \prof{Professor 1}
\end{flushright}

\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

#### Edited later

I'm looking for an elegant way to show the TOC, meaning to show that chapters are belonged to the Part. Hyphenation is an ugly way for me. I'm open to any suggestion that will display an elegant TOC for a collective document.

Comment: Does that work? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132266/how-to-turn-off-hyphenation-in-toc-only

Comment: @Ingmar unfortunately is not working for me. I also tried `\begingroup
\RaggedRight \tableofcontents \endgroup` and is not working

Comment: Why do you think that `\RaggedRight` disables hyphenation? Are you maybe confusing it with `\raggedright`?

Comment: @Mico I found it here and I tried> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139740/hyphenation-in-a-table-of-contents-causing-bad-blocks

Comment: @Mafsi -- Please note what I wrote below the accepted answer in the link you provided: "The `\RaggedRight` [command] won't prohibit all hyphenation. To really turn off all hyphenation in a flush-left setting, use `\raggedright` (note: no uppercase letters)". Still don't believe me? Here's an excerpt from the abstract of the user guide of the `ragged2e` package (which provides the `\RaggedRight` macro): "This package provides new commands and environments ... which are easy to configure to allow hyphenation."

Comment: @Mico I'm open to any suggestion that will make a TOC elegant. I'm not good in LaTeX, so I found how to use tocloft  today. If there is any way to make Chapters indented in order to show belonging to the Part, I can accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your MWE, for which thank you.

```
\bgroup    % keep non-hyphenation local to the ToC
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\tableofcontents
\egroup
```

Processing your MWE shows that chapters are indented wrt to parts in the ToC, so you already have that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never thought of that, although it was in front of my eyes!